# JSON issue with MongoDB ObjectId

Tags: python, json, mongodb, bson

As you know MongoDB documents has at least one `ObjectId` named `_id`. It's not possible to convert a document contains an `ObjectId` to `JSON`. currently I have two solutions to convert this document to `JSON`:

```
del doc['_id']
```

or create a new document with a string instance of that field.

What it just works when I know which field contains `ObjectId`. What to do if I have multiple `ObjectId` and I don't know what are they?

Comment: this is vague - It's not possible to convert a document contains an objectId to json

Comment: @VanPeer So how ORMs handle this?

Comment: I meant what you said is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoDB returns a `BSON` (not a `JSON`) document, so actually you want to convert a `BSON` document into `JSON` document.

Try to take a look into this artickle: https://technobeans.com/2012/09/10/mongodb-convert-bson-to-json/